# Washboard as Instrument

Tags: instruments

I know that some washboards are fabricated from the outset to be musical instruments.

Are they significantly better than using just any old antique washboard I might happen to find around?

I'm asking as a complete amateur who's just looking to screw around with a garage band full of other complete amateurs.

Answer (score 1):

They only exist because it's harder to find 'any old antique washboard' anywhere. If you can find a real washboard, you get bonus points for authenticity.